# OneNote API : Set Rule Lines options

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Is it possible to set the Rule Lines options, under the View tab using the OneNote api.

I've had a look at the page and content end points but can't see anything that suggests itself.

Comment: This option is currently not supported through the API.
I would encourage you to submit your idea to: https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis, with enough votes this could get picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this when creating a new page via the api. If you have a template page that is ruled and use **page: copyToSection** the resultant page will also be ruled.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/pages/<id>/copyToSection
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 52

{
  "id": "id-value",
  "groupId": "groupId-value"
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Posting Yanir's comment as an answer:

This option is currently not supported through the API. I would encourage you to submit your idea to: onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis, so we can explore working on it.

Comment: Added to user voice. https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/14152797-ability-to-set-rule-lines-via-api